# Query is really annoying me I can't get my head around it

Tags: sql, select, join, erd

I am new to SQL and I have the the following erd: 
[image: ERD diagram for a haulage site]

The query I am looking to perform is:
What quantity of vehicles can be used to service shipment x?|

Any Ideas??
I have:

```
select count(VehicleType) from Vehicle where in
 (select VEHICLETYPE, SHIPMENT_TYPE from can_carry
 where SHIPMENT_TYPE in
 (select SHIPMENT_TYPE from Shipment where ContractNo = x and ShipmentNo = x  );
```

but I feel like it is wrong

Comment: something missing between WHERE and IN. (According to the SQL Validator, http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/.)

Comment: Can't you count them at the can_carry table? Kindof like this

`select count(VEHICLETYPE) from can_carry
 where can_carry.SHIPMENT_TYPE in
 (select SHIPMENT_TYPE from Shipment where ContractNo = x and ShipmentNo = x  )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent a VEHICLETYPE in first condition and one missing ).
So this is valid your valid SQL:

```
select count(VehicleType) from Vehicle where VEHICLETYPE in
(select VEHICLETYPE, SHIPMENT_TYPE from can_carry
 where SHIPMENT_TYPE in
 (select SHIPMENT_TYPE from Shipment where ContractNo = x and ShipmentNo = x))
```

But this SQL is PERFKILLER! :)
I mean that you selecting 3 sets of results! So this will have a horrible execution plan.
You can write a better query with using [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). More about execution plans [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/).

Comment: Thanks for that I thought about using joins but I'm not sure it would be something like select count(VehicleType) from Vehicle join can_carry using (VehicleType), join Shipment using (SHIPMENT_TYPE) where where ContractNo = x and ShipmentNo = x ; But it seemed too easy ?

Comment: Yes, you can write it via join. If i will have a time, i will try it and insert to answer a correct query ;) But I am in hurry now.

Comment: If I can advise, read about execution plans. If developer write bad SQL, it will be really problem for future. If you have a big amount of data in DB and you are running query like this, you will have a problems with connection pools and timeouts etc.... Really bad :) Believe me :)))